# How DragDrop features work in WPF? Deep understanding of DragDrop and related events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to completely understand DragDrop features of WPF.

**Background:**

*I'm trying to use DragDrop in WPF for a bit diffrent purposes that it was designed.
By "diffrent purposes" I mean that it will not carry data to be copied, moved or pasted. I'm working on diagram drawing application and DragDrop will be used to move "diagram elements", resize them or connect their "attachment points" with lines. All DragDrop operations will happen inside of some `Canvas`, `UserControls` representing "diagram elements" or "connector lines".*

**So far, I understand that:**

1. DragDrop operation starts when I initialize it by calling this method:

   ```
   public static DragDropEffects DoDragDrop(DependencyObject dragSource, object data, DragDropEffects allowedEffects)
   ```

   for example in some `MouseMove` event handler (conditionally - if the mouse button is pressed)

   My understanding of this is `DoDragDrop` method stores passed `dragSource` and `data` somewhere.
2. DragDrop operation ends when:

   - I have registered `Drop` event handler on some `UIElement` and that event fires
   - `Esc` key has been pressed

   By operation end I mean that there will be no more `Drop` event handlers called when I release mouse key over `UIElement` that has `AllowDrop` set to `true`.
3. `DragOver` event has no impact on whole operation (it is still "in progress", but I can check what is currently being dragged and check `DataObject` being carried.
4. To do DragDrop operation properly all I have to do is:

   - call `DragDrop.DoDragDrop()`
   - use `DragOver` event handler to update interface if necessary (like moving "diagram elements" or redraw/modify "connector lines" on my `Canvas` if user needs to see what is going on
   - use `Drop` event handler to finish operation

**Questions**

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Is it good idea to use `DragDrop` built in WPF for such application, or maybe I should write something based on MouseUp and MouseDown from scratch?

   I'm asking because my first tries end with big `Drop` handler methods where I have to write few conditions to check context of drop operation (what was dropped? control that represents "diagram element", end of "connector line" or maybe something else). Also I have to "pack" data for `DoDragDrop` method in `MouseMove` handler methods, and then cast them to proper type in `Drop` (or `DragOver`) event. I'm thinking about writing some custom separate events for dragging "connector lines" over a "worksheet", something like `CreatingConnectorDrop`, `MovingConnectorAttachmentPointDrop` etc.
3. Can anyone recommend some source of information useful for writing this type of drawing application? Like some github repository, book...

Answer (score 0):

The drag source calls `DoDragDrop`, e.g., from the `MouseMove` handler, to initialize a drag operation with the involved data as its argument.

The drop target must handle the `DragEnter`, `DragLeave` or `DragOver` attached events (and their corresponding tunneling versions) to manipulate the drag effect (by setting the `DragEventArgs.Effects` property).

Handle the `GiveFeedback` event and tunneling versions to provide a drag feedback e.g. to highlight illegal drop targets or potential drop targets in general.

The drop target handles the the `Drop` event to accept the dropped data.
Since all drag & drop events are routed events, the `Drop` event can always be handled by every element in the current UI element (sub)tree, unless the routed event is explicitly marked as handled by the tree's root element (tunneling) or leaf element (bubbling).

I recommend to read the [Microsoft Docs: Drag and Drop Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to learn more.

Using the existing Drag & Drop framework infrastructure is absolutely recommended. It makes the enabling of drop support for a particular control very convenient (simply set the `UIElement.AllowDrop` to `true`).
Additionally, it uses dedicated bubbling and tunneling events. Opposed to your suggested mouse events, this avoids the drag & drop logic from being broken due to the internal mouse event handling of the participating controls.
Another benefit of using the provided infrastructure is that WPF controls like text boxes already implement a specific drag and drop behavior, that reflects the UX of the Windows OS.